# C# - Select certain text from quotation marks in textbox.Text and save them in textfile

Tags: c#, extract

Is there a way to select text in Info="" and put that info in a textfile?

For example, i have a xml file that contains all the data. I copy all that xml text and paste it on my textbox.Text and then click a button and it removes the "". For example

```
string names = "Names=\"";
string ages = "\" Ages=\"";
string last = "\"";

textbox.Text = clip_board.Text.Replace(names, """);
textbox.Text = clip_board.Text.Replace(ages, "");
textbox.Text = clip_board.Text.Replace(last, "");
#It will show me James 28
```

I only want the text that is in Names="" and save those names in a textfile.
Is there a way to do this and ignore the rest of the xml even if it is in the textbox.text? The whole xml text has to be in that textbox.text so how can i only get the names in Names="" and save them in a textfile?

Comment: It sounds like a text box may not be the most appropriate control, as it sounds like you have a distinct set of information (Names, Ages).

Comment: Halo.  Work on better questions and you have not accepted a single answer.

Comment: i know but i do need a textbox/richtextbox to put that information and i need that button to convert that information in "" to a text file

Answer (score 3):

If you're inserting quotation marks into the `TextBox`, you can do the following to remove these quotation marks:

```
string s = NameOfTextBox.Text.Replace("\"", "");
```

### EDIT:

You can also try this if you insert many things into the TextBox:

```
char[] sep = { ' ' };
string[] info = NameOfTextBox.Text.Split(sep);
for(int i=0; i<info.Length; i++)
    info[i] = info[i].Substring(info[i].IndexOf("\"")).Replace("\"", "");
```

Then, you have an array of the info you inserted inside the quotes. It wasn't tested but should work.

Comment: I know that works but the problem is that there are other informations like Ages="". I only want to remove the "" from Names="" and only get the names and display only them on a textfile.

Comment: Edited accordingly @OWSAP

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: StartIndex cannot be less than zero.

Comment: It worked for me. You might not use it correctly. Do you have anything else beside what I gave you that affects the text?

Comment: Just added that code and added Name="James" Ages="21" to the textbox and did not do nothing. Then added a space after Names to try it out and got that error

Comment: With this code, it shouldn't contain space between `Name` and `=`. Are you sure you didn't keep those `String.Replace` methods you posted in your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(Textbox.Text, "\"([^\"]*)\""))
   //do something with the info.
```

I may be misreading your question. But this would return the information in the double quotes from the Textbox.

Explanation: negation as regex option. Leaves only `James` or `28`.